# 'rfm_table_order' function in rfm package in R, returning a tibble. But tibble output is visible only in console, unable to View it in R or export it

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, tibble

I am working on customer segmentation problem. And working on `rfm` package in R. While using `rfm_table_order` function, I am storing its output in `rfm_result` variable (which is created as tibble by default). After running the `rfm_result`, the console is showing a correct number of variables and observations. But, in a global environment rfm_result is showing only 5 variable and 0 observations. So I am unable to View the entire `rfm_result` dataset. Also, I cannot export it as `rfm_result` is getting stored only as an empty dataset in the csv file. Please help.

I tried to convert the tibble into dataFrame which is not working. Still, rfm_result has 0 observations

**Code:**

```
rfm_result <- rfm_table_order(data, CustomerID, InvoiceDate, Amount, analysis_date)
```

**Output in Console** (It is showing a correct number of rows and columns):

```
A tibble: 3,891 x 9
   customer_id date_most_recent recency_days transaction_count  amount recency_score frequency_score monetary_score rfm_score
         <int> <date>                  <dbl>             <dbl>   <dbl>         <int>           <int>          <int>     <dbl>
 1       12346 2011-01-18                326                 2     0               1               1              1       111
 2       12747 2011-12-07                  3                96  3837.              5               4              5       545
 3       12748 2011-12-09                  1              4279 27215.              5               5              5       555
 4       12749 2011-12-06                  4               231  3868.              5               5              5       555
 5       12820 2011-12-06                  4                59   942.              5               4              4       544
 6       12821 2011-05-09                215                 6    92.7             1               1              1       111
 7       12822 2011-09-30                 71                47   919.              2               3              4       234
 8       12823 2011-09-26                 75                 5  1760.              2               1              4       214
 9       12824 2011-10-11                 60                25   397.              3               2              2       322
10       12826 2011-12-07                  3                94  1468.              5               4              4       544

# ... with 3,881 more rows
```

But Global Environment is showing 0 observations and 5 variables for tibble `rfm_result`

Also, if I check the dimension of `rfm_result` with dim(rfm_result), I am getting the output as 0 observations and 5 variables only.

I am not even able to export this tibble via `write.csv()` function. Its exporting blank CSV file.

Please help, how can I export this tibble in csv or View this tibble R.

Answer (score 1):

```
class(rfm_result)
  [1] "rfm_table_order" "tibble"          "data.frame"
```

```
rfm_result$rfm
```

the above code will show you the whole result.

```
#converting to csv
write.table(result$rfm,file="rfm_results.csv",sep=",",append=FALSE,row.names = FALSE)
```